# Query: I have 4 rows, need to add the results from 3 rows into one, and leave the last row untouched

Tags: mysql, sql, rows

I have a kind of tricky question for this query. First the code:

```
SELECT user_type.user_type_description,COUNT(incident.user_id) as Quantity
FROM incident
INNER JOIN user ON incident.user_id=user.user_id
INNER JOIN user_type ON user.user_type=user_type.user_type
WHERE incident.code=2
GROUP BY user.user_type
```

What Am I doing?

For example, I am counting police reports of robbery, made from different kind of users. In my example, "admin" users reported 6 incidents of code "2" (robbery) and so on, as is showed in 'where' clause (incident must be robbery, also code 2).

this brings the following result:

```
+-----------------------+----------+
| user_type_description | Quantity |
+-----------------------+----------+
| Admin                 |        6 |
| Moderator             |        8 |
| Fully_registered_user |        8 |
| anonymous_user        |        9 |
+-----------------------+----------+
```

Basically `Admin,Moderator and Fully_registered_user` are `appropriately registered users`. I need to add them in a result where it shows like:

```
+--------------+------------+
| Proper_users | Anonymous  |
+--------------+------------+
|           22 |          9 |
+--------------+------------+
```

I am not good with `sql`. Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Show your sample data and expected result with formatted table.. You can use [This](https://ozh.github.io/ascii-tables/) And your group by is weird.. Your select use `user_type.user_type_description` but your group by `user.user_type`

Comment: I used your link, but stackoverflow just omits spaces. Yes, I group by user type, which is a number. 0=admin 1=mod 2=fully_reg_user 3=anonymous.  user_type_description contains the text description for those numbers.

Comment: I can't follow you if you don't show sample data..

Comment: Ok! Let me see.

I am counting police reports of robbery, made from different kind of users. In my example, "admin" users reported 6 incidents of code "2" (robbery) and so on, as is showed in 'where' clause (incident must be robbery, also code 2)
Hope that helps a bit.

Comment: Put it on your question to provide more info..

Comment: Done. And two geniuses posted some wonderful responses. Thanks for all the help.

Answer (score 2):

You can try to use condition aggregate function base on your current result set.

`SUM` with `CASE WHEN` expression.

```
SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN user_type_description IN ('Admin','Moderator','Fully_registered_user') THEN Quantity END) Proper_users,
       SUM(CASE WHEN user_type_description = 'anonymous_user' THEN Quantity END) Anonymous
FROM (
    SELECT user_type.user_type_description,COUNT(incident.user_id) as Quantity
    FROM incident
    INNER JOIN user ON incident.user_id=user.user_id
    INNER JOIN user_type ON user.user_type=user_type.user_type
    WHERE incident.code=2
    GROUP BY user.user_type
) t1
```

Answer (score 2):

You just need conditional aggregation:

```
SELECT SUM( ut.user_type_description IN ('Admin', 'Moderator', 'Fully_registered_user') ) as Proper_users,
        SUM( ut.user_type_description IN ('anonymous_user') as anonymous
FROM incident i INNER JOIN
     user u
     ON i.user_id = u.user_id INNER JOIN
     user_type ut
     ON u.user_type = ut.user_type
WHERE i.code = 2;
```

Notes:

- Table aliases make the query easier to write and to read.
- This uses a MySQL shortcut for adding values -- just just adding the booelean expressions.

Answer (score 1):

I would solve it with a [CTE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/with.html), but it would be better to have this association in a table.

```
WITH
user_type_categories
AS
(
    SELECT 'Admin' AS [user_type_description] , 'Proper_users' AS [user_type_category]  
    UNION SELECT 'Moderator' AS [user_type_description] , 'Proper_users' AS [user_type_category]  
    UNION SELECT 'Fully_registered_user' AS [user_type_description] , 'Proper_users' AS [user_type_category]  
    UNION SELECT 'anonymous_user' AS [user_type_description] , 'Anonymous' AS [user_type_category]  
)
SELECT 
      CASE WHEN utc.[user_type_category] = 'Proper_users' THEN
        SUM(incident.user_id) 
      END AS [Proper_Users_Quantity]
     , CASE WHEN utc.[user_type_category] = 'Anonymous' THEN
        SUM(incident.user_id) 
      END AS [Anonymous_Quantity]
FROM 
    [incident]
    INNER JOIN [user] ON [incident].[user_id] = [user].[user_id]
    INNER JOIN [user_type] ON [user].[user_type] = [user_type].[user_type]
    LEFT JOIN user_type_categories AS utc ON utc.[user_type_description] = [user_type].[user_type_description]
WHERE 
    [incident].[code] = 2
```

Comment: Holy guacamole. I am not allowed to put this code but I will take note of this solution.